# How do I determine how efficient my furnace, A/C, and windows are?

Tags: hvac, windows, utilities

I just bought an older home.

The furnace, A/C, and windows are functional, but I suspect there may be some efficiency gains to be made.

Is there any way to determine/estimate how efficient those are currently? I would like to see if it makes sense to spend the money to upgrade them based on ROI on my utility bills.

Comment: this question is far too broad as it stands. The only answer to the question as you posed it is "hire someone to do an energy efficiency audit"

Comment: @mac: Does an "energy efficiency audit" require expensive, specialized tools?  If not, I see no reason why he couldn't do that himself.

Comment: As far as I am concerned an energy audit is a good answer - I am aware that the question is broad. I honestly did not know whether the task of estimating energy consumption of a home was something that could be done with any sort of accuracy.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft A [blower door](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blower_door) is a couple grand, an [infrared camera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermographic_camera) is another couple grand. So for a cool ~$4000.00 you can do your own energy audit, but you'd better find some big problems if you want to save $4,000.00 on your energy bills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mac has mentioned, an energy audit is a logical starting point.  I would shop for a "blower door" test that measures actual system air leakage.  The other test would be a thermal IR scan, that will reveal relative hot/cold spots.  Some utilities offer discounted audits.